# Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, typeerror

I'm trying to create **SignalR chat** application, but I couldn't resolve this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read  property 'chatHub' of undefined

[image: View 1st Error Image : hubs not found]

[image: View 2nd Error Image : $.connection.chatHub]

I have written my code below, please check.

**ChatHub.cs**:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRMVC.Models
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```cs
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRMVC.Models.Startup))]
namespace SignalRMVC.Models
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**Chat.cshtml**:

```html
<script>
    $(function () {

        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };

        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

        $('#message').focus();

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });

    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you dont load jquery multiple times, can you check your `layout` to see if jquery is loaded again there ?

Comment: The proxy script is not loading... you can check it by opening the URL /signalr/hubs

open the source from browser and click the link of this script, see what URL it makes